# Error while creating a new CSP customer through Powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, scripting

I´m getting the following error

> New-PartnerCustomer : Organization registration id information is missing

I´m trying to create new customeer using this commnand:

```
Connect-PartnerCenter  \\ enter CSP credentials
```

then executed command `New-PartnerCustomer` as below:

```
New-PartnerCustomer -BillingAddressLine1 'Rua Jambeiro, 128' -BillingAddressCity 'OSASCO' -BillingAddressCountry 'BR' -BillingAddressPostalCode '06184280’ -BillingAddressState 'São Paulo' -ContactEmail 'mathieu@embratel.com.br' -ContactFirstName 'Mathieu' -ContactLastName 'Coletti' -ContactPhoneNumber '+55(11)666'  -Culture 'pt-BR' -Domain 'matcoletti.onmicrosoft.com' -Language 'pt' -Name 'MATHIEU COLETTI LTDA'
```

I´ve tried to find out what parameter should I use to specify the Org Registration Id but I didnt find anything on google. It seems that parameters does not exist.

Comment: How's going? Has your issue got resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the official [create user REST API reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/partner-center/develop/create-a-customer)(PowerShell is built on top of REST API), you can find the param in [company profile section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/partner-center/develop/create-a-customer#company-profile):

> The customer’s organization registration number (also referred to as
> INN number in certain countries). Only required for customer’s
> company/organization located in the following countries: Armenia(AM),
> Azerbaijan(AZ), Belarus(BY), Hungary(HU), Kazakhstan(KZ),
> Kyrgyzstan(KG), Moldova(MD), Russia(RU), Tajikistan(TJ),
> Uzbekistan(UZ), Ukraine(UA), Brazil(BR), India, South Africa, Poland,
> United Arab Emirates, Saudi Arabia, Turkey, Thailand, Vietnam,
> Myanmar, Iraq, South Sudan and Venezuela. For customer’s
> company/organization located in other countries this is an optional
> field.

I also checked `New-PartnerCustomer` command, there is no param for this value, so I am afraid partner center powershell not works here. I suggest you use REST API to do this, you can specify `organizationRegistrationNumber` in `CompanyProfile` of the request body, just as below:

```
{
    "CompanyProfile": {
        "Domain": "XXX.onmicrosoft.com",
        "organizationRegistrationNumber":"xxxxx"
    },
    "BillingProfile": {
        "Culture": "br-pt",
        "Email": "XXX@XXX.com.br",
        "Language": "pt",
        "CompanyName": "XXXX",
        "DefaultAddress": {
            "FirstName": "Test",
            "LastName": "Test",
            "AddressLine1": "Rua Jambeiro, 128",
            "City": "OSASCO",
            "State": "São Paulo",
            "PostalCode": "06184280",
            "Country": "br",
            "phoneNumber": "123456"
        }
    }
}
```

If you are not sure the organization registration number of your region, just raise a support ticket from partner center portal=> Support => Partner support requests.